# Reloading kernel by hibernation

Tags: linux-kernel, hibernate

I am asking this out of curiosity after updating my computer...

beforehand, I want to make it clear - as far as I understand - that hibernation is the term for unloading the current state of the operating system into the disk (swap-space) and powering down the system completely in order to be able to resume the system later.

**Now for the actual question**

Let's say I updated my kernel and let my system into hibernation. When I power on my system again wouldn't it be the newer version of the kernel that is booted and loads the suspended state from swap-space? And thus (Kind of but not really) saving me a reboot?
*even though rebooting often feels quicker than restoring from hibernation*

My hypothesis is that `uname -r` changes after updating and hibernating (assuming that the kernel is not immediately reloaded after updating).

I came to think about this after recently enabling hibernation by setting the kernel parameter `resume=/dev/sdXY`

Comment: AFAIK, the reason for the swap partition to be (at least) as big as your total RAM as a requirement for hibernation is that your whole memory needs to be mirrored into the swap, (included blank or unallocated pages). and also including kernel code, data, IVT, etc. So that leads me to believe that no, when the system wakes up it's still run the old kernel and you need a complete reboot to load the updated image. I could be wrong though, let's wait for the experts answers, BTW, are you sure /dev/sdXY doesn't point to your swap partition?. BTW2 xD. I don't see anything wrong with your english.

Comment: Actually I used `resume=UUID=<long ass UUID>` but `/dev/sdXY` should also be valid.